# selenium-chromedriver-java WebDriverException

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

while I invoke chromedriver, WebDriverException caught:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"1816.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 118 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-IU99086', ip: '192.168.2.59', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7316_19770}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=54.0.2840.71, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 4bfeb224c89336380e968727435630be
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at com.changcai.test.SeleniumChromeDriverTest.main(SeleniumChromeDriverTest.java:15)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just gone through this problem. As some other people said, it's a chromedriver version issue.

Downloading new one [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/) should fix the problem.

Hope it helps.